# Xcode UITesting LoginUser redirect to homeScreen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

The problem i am facing is i want to redirect the logged in user to home screen through launch arguments but the function is not working 
Here is my function

```
func testL_SettingScreen() {
    app.launchArguments.append("HomeScreen")
    app.launch()
    app.staticTexts["No Alerts detected around you."].exists
    app.buttons["MenuBtn"].tap()
}
```

And am calling the launch arguments in my didfinishlaunchingwithoptions in app delegate like this

```
if CommandLine.arguments.contains("HomeScreen"), let user = HelperClass.decode() {
        user.cellVerified = "1"
        HelperClass.encode(savedPerson: user)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use `launchEnvironment` instead?

Something like:

```
func testL_SettingScreen() {
    app.launchEnvironment = ["HomeScreen": "YES"]
    app.launch()
    app.staticTexts["No Alerts detected around you."].exists
    app.buttons["MenuBtn"].tap()
}
```

Then in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let environment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
let value = environment["HomeScreen"] != nil
if value, let user = HelperClass.decode() {
        user.cellVerified = "1"
        HelperClass.encode(savedPerson: user)
}
```